# How to move core js files into the footer

Tags: javascript, optimization, wp-filesystem

while testing for page speed, i found 2 js files that causes the speed delay, according to [PageSpeed Insight](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights). files names are

1. /wp-includes/js/swfobject.js
2. /wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js

how can i moved these files into the footer, currently both files are loading in header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this Plugin [Minit](https://github.com/kasparsd/minit).
this plugin combine JS and CSS files and serve them from the uploads folder.
Although this plugin is not listed on [Wordpress Plugin Directory](http://wordpress.org/plugins/), dnt no why.
But it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should not disturb core files, lets say even if you copy those files in footer and tomorrow wordpress releases another new version, and you update it. The files that you moved from /wp-includes/js/... will be back. In my opnion, try to minimize them. Although you be fine with wordpress core files, when optimizing your site and focus on optimizing html and css (and JS, if you made any)

Comment: ya, you are saying right. although all other js files which i used shifted to footer.

Answer (score 1):

have you found the file which enqueues those jquery files??

if found then set the last parameter of the wp_enqueue_script() function to true;

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

For more details refer to : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: i tried alot, but didn't find the file although same technique i was using for other js files.